# Checking if a record already exists in database, if no insert else increment the count field

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-music-player

I created a sqlite database to store the songs which are most played by the user. Basically, I'm creating "Most played songs" playlist for my music app. The logic I'm using is, when the user selects a song, it is send to the database. If is already there in the database, an integer field will increment its value else the song will be added to database. And I display the result according to the integer field(song with most integer value will be displayed on the top).But my app does't do the sorting according to the integer value. I don't know what is wrong.

Code to add songs:

```
 public void addSong(SongInfoModel songInfoModel){


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, songInfoModel.getSongID());
    values.put(KEY_NAME, songInfoModel.getSongName());
    values.put(KEY_ARTIST, songInfoModel.getArtistName());
    values.put(KEY_DURATION, songInfoModel.getDuration());
    values.put(KEY_LAST_PLAYED, getDateTime());
    values.put(KEY_ART, songInfoModel.getAlbumIDArtwork());

    if(!CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(songInfoModel)) {
        values.put(KEY_MOST_PLAYED, count);
        Log.i("Doesn't Exists:", String.valueOf(count));
    }
    else {
        values.put(KEY_MOST_PLAYED, count++);
        Log.i("Exists:", String.valueOf(count));
    }

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();

    Log.i("Time song was clicked:", getDateTime());
```

Code to check if song already exists:

```
 public  boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(SongInfoModel songInfoModel) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + KEY_ID + " = " + songInfoModel.getSongID();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

Code to display the array of songs:

```
 public ArrayList<SongInfoModel> getMostPlayed(){

    ArrayList<SongInfoModel> mpList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + KEY_MOST_PLAYED + " DESC";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{

            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            String SongName = cursor.getString(1);
            String artistName = cursor.getString(2);
            long dur = cursor.getLong(3);
            String Art = cursor.getString(5);


            SongInfoModel sh = new SongInfoModel(id,SongName,artistName,dur,null,Art);

            mpList.add(sh);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }cursor.close();



    return mpList;
```

Comment: how did you define "KEY_MOST_PLAYED" in the table, is it INTEGER? how is the query result? can you give me a result list? pay attention that you have inserted  **count** from your table before increasing.

Comment: Yes it is an integer. And the reason why I inserted "count" is because if song is not present it will add the song and set count will remain 0 but if song is already in the database and I play the same song then count will increase. Hope you are getting my point.

Comment: I got your point, but you could use "KEY_MOST_PLAYED" to check whether exist or not. Anyway, you have to increase a number after playing a special music. please send me the table, so my answer will be more accurate.

Comment: That is what count++ is doing. Key_most_played has count value. So the song which has most count value will be displayed first followed by the rest.

Comment: Please suggest me what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Change to boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot to int CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot,

```
public  int CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(SongInfoModel songInfoModel) {
        int mostPlayed=-1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select KEY_MOST_PLAYED from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + KEY_ID + " = " + songInfoModel.getSongID();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return -1;
        }else {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                mostPlayed = cursor.getInt(....)
            }


        }
        cursor.close();
        return mostPlayed;
    }
```

then use

```
count = CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(songInfoModel)+1;
//add count to SongInfoModel
values.put(KEY_MOST_PLAYED, count);
db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
db.close();
```

Comment: Thank you Hamze for your time and answer. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if the song doesn't exist you want to add it, if the song does exist then you want to increment the count of how many times the song has been played within the song.

In SQLite terms new song = **INSERT**, change song (count) = **UPDATE**.

You appear to only attempt to **INSERT**, which would either add another row for the song or not add one due to the KEY_ID already existing (or other constraints). Which, depends upon how the KEY_ID column has been defined. I suspect the latter which would explain the sort not working as expected due to the count never being increased.

Additionally **`count++`** (post increment) increments the value **AFTER** the value has been applied. So that to would have resulted in the count not being incremented even though the message in the log would indicate that it has been incremented. **`++count`** (pre increment) increments the value **BEFORE** it is applied, so this has been used.

As such I believe that you need something along the lines of :-

```
public void addSong(SongInfoModel songInfoModel){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    if(!CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(songInfoModel)) {
        values.put(KEY_ID, songInfoModel.getSongID());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, songInfoModel.getSongName());
        values.put(KEY_ARTIST, songInfoModel.getArtistName());
        values.put(KEY_DURATION, songInfoModel.getDuration());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_PLAYED, getDateTime());
        values.put(KEY_ART, songInfoModel.getAlbumIDArtwork());
        values.put(KEY_MOST_PLAYED, count);
        Log.i("Doesn't Exists:", String.valueOf(count));
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }
    else {
        values.put(KEY_MOST_PLAYED, ++count);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,
            KEY_ID + "=?,
            new String[]{songInfoModel.getSongID()}
        );
        Log.i("Exists:", String.valueOf(count));
    }

    db.close();
    Log.i("Time song was clicked:", getDateTime());
}
```

Notes 
- The code hasn't been checked so it may contain errors.

Comment: Best answer I've ever got! Thank you so much Mike! By the way can you tell me how the db.update works?

Comment: But there is one problem though, I noticed that if I play song "A" 3 times(count=3) and then I play another song "B", then the count of song "B" starts from 3(it doesn't start from 0).

Comment: You don't show how you get/determine **`count`**, perhaps in the INSERT you should hard code 0 by using `values.put(KEY_MOST_PLAYED,0);` (or set the DEFAULT value to 0 and not use `values.put(KEY_MOST_PLAYED)`) and then in the UPDATE use `count = songInfoModel.get??????()` (where ????? is the appropriate getter for the most played value) putting this line immediately before the line `values.put(KEY_MOST_PLAYED, ++count);`

Comment: I have private int count =0  defined

Comment: Count is not something user enters or is passed. I have defined and initialized count =0 in the beginning of the class.

Comment: That's the issue, you need to extract the most played value from the current song when updating a song or use the query to increment the value when updating.

Comment: How to do you propose I do that? Because media store in android doesn't support "most played". The only way is to implement ones own logic.

Comment: The logic is as described above the count (KEY_MOST_PLAYED) is taken from and manipulated according to your database. i.e. a) new song set KEY_MOST_PLAYED to 0 with b) play a song then get KEY_MOST_PLAYED for the song and increment it. i.e. The Database you created supports the most played extension.